# Ensuring a delay in an Ansible 'with_sequence' loop

Tags: ansible

I've the following handler that is invoked correctly, however, all the sequences appear to be run in quick succession.  I'd like to run one by one with a specified delay. Will this work?

```yaml
- name: 'restart process_server_x_instance_y'
  shell: '/bin/restarter serverx_instance_{{item}}'
  ignore_errors: yes
  delay: 5
  with_sequence: count={{ number_of_instances|length }}
```

Is this enough to pause 5 secs after restarting `instance_1`,
then 5 secs after `instance_2`, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `loop_control` - `pause`:

```
- name: 'restart process_server_x_instance_y'
  shell: '/bin/restarter serverx_instance_{{item}}'
  ignore_errors: yes
  with_sequence: count={{ number_of_instances|length }}
  loop_control:
    pause: 5
```