# Ansible: How to add a delay to a sequence?

Tags: ansible

A question for [sequence lookup – generate a list based on a number sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/sequence.html).

Suppose I want to deploy several docker containers on the same host, like this:

```yaml
- name: launch the containers
  with_sequence: count={{ amount_of_test_containers }}
  docker_container:
    name: 'testcontainer-{{ item }}'
    ...
```

But I want there to be a sleep between each of the container launches/restarts? How would I do that?

I've tried adding `delay` above `with_sequence` but that's not working.

The reason for wanting this: an other service connects to them and if they're all restarted really soon after each other, than can drop connectivity.

By adding a delay, at least 1 can stay connected at all time, I'm hoping.

---

**Changed Description and Use Case**

Thanks for the comments ... While those do work for adding a delay, I found that what I actually want is a port check every X seconds until the return is a specific code, indicating that the service is up.

For which is is necessary to split out the bringing up of the service to another task file.

So from `main.yml` you can then do `include_tasks: start.yml`, add the sequence to that.

And then in `start.yml` you start the service and do the `uri` check with `until: result is success`.

Comment: Have you considered addressing this problem by managing your service through docker-compose ? This would let you update and scale and is still compatible with ansible automation (with module `docker_compose`).

Comment: @Zeitounator I had not considered it, as I have never worked with docker compose before. Nothing in my deploys uses it, so I'm thinking it would be a pretty big change if I did? Except if Ansible makes it easier.

Comment: i think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267938/ensuring-a-delay-in-an-ansible-with-sequence-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ensuring a delay in an ansible with\_sequence loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267938/ensuring-a-delay-in-an-ansible-with-sequence-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Use loop_control: pause feature to add the delay.

Answer (score 0):

> "*How to add a delay to a sequence?*"

The minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Sequence with delay
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%T') }}"
    loop: "{{ range(0, 4 +1) | list }}"
    loop_control:
      pause: 5 # seconds
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Sequence with delay] ***
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg: 09:00:23
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 09:00:28
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 09:00:33
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 09:00:38
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) =>
  msg: 09:00:43
```

> *I've tried adding `delay` above `with_sequence` but that's not working.*

and work as expected according the output.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ensuring a delay in an Ansible `with_sequence` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268242/6771046)

**Further Documentation**

- [`loop` with `range` function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence)
- [Pausing within a `loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#pausing-within-a-loop)
- [`pipe` lookup – read output from a command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pipe_lookup.html#examples)