# Ansible playbook sleep inbetween loop

Tags: linux, ansible, rhel

I have an Ansible playbook containing task in which runs on multiple variables.

```yaml
- name: task
  module:
    XXX:
  with_items: "{{ items }}"
```

How do I add a sub-task to the task below to sleep for one minute between each variable?

Many thanks.

Comment: The description seems to be too generic (for me). Without providing further information and description about the task itself and what you try to achieve this question might not be answerable. On behalf you may have a look into [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) and with which you could define a `delay`.

Comment: I was able to address my question using loop_control as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267938/ensuring-a-delay-in-an-ansible-with-sequence-loop)

Comment: So it is actually then just [Pausing within a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#pausing-within-a-loop).